# Git repository sniffer

Tags: git, google-chrome-extension, trayicon

I am looking for application(desktop or chrome extension or firefox extension) that listen to all of the changes that git repository can have, and send push notification status about that changes, in order to notify all the participant in the development will know about it. I tried to google it for some time, but, with no result.

Any Idea?

thx.

Comment: is this a comletely local repository? or is it on some server? (if so, which server software? github, gitolite, etc?)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to make use of the post-update hook on the upstream repo. From there you can script curl or wget to do something that you want on another machine.

If you're using github, they have some proprietary ones you can use to get notifications: https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks

if you are using gitolite, make sure you don't zap the update hook as it is how it integrates itself to enable its functionality. Update the update.secondary hook instead. I believe the latest versions of gitolite have better instrumentation for administrating hooks than earlier versions.

Answer (score 0):

Extending Adam answer, you can have an event listener for all triggers from github in background page and use Desktop Notifications API for pushing latest updates.

## References

- [Desktop Notifications](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html)
- [Background Pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html)